# Teamcity agent configure command line to build a image and run it

Tags: teamcity

I guess this may be in document/manual somewhere, but I just can't find it.

Would like the agent to run the following two commands after checking out source from svn

- make integration
- engine -full

But there is no obvious place to configure agent to do it in the agent page among the following tabs:

```
Agent Summary
Build History
Compatible Configurations
Build Runners
Agent Logs
Agent Parameters
```

Comment: Your question is really unclear.  What are you trying to do - configure an agent, or use TeamCity to build software?

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some more reading of the documentation and with TeamCity it's all available online at http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/documentation/

Comment: Yes Sir. More reading will definitely help, but internet has made many of us too impatient to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TeamCity models projects with build configurations, agents don't have much configuration as they are meant to be reused for all your compatible projects. Build configurations are used to set up the source code to pull, the build actions/steps to perform, and what outputs/artifacts to capture and store.

If you jump into the Administration area of TeamCity you'll be able to create a new project, and configure build steps on a build configuration. You can create build steps for common tools like MSBuild and Ant, however you can also just run any shell commands with the Command Line build step.

The TeamCity documentation outlines how to configure build steps very well:
http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+Build+Steps